# Android debugger show me there is a problem with the xml file, but I can not find one

Tags: xml, android-studio

have since today the problem that with the dubugger in android studio in colors.xml displays a problem but I can not find it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Customise your theme here -->
<color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
<color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
<color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
<color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#455cde</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#403d3d</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#c2bdbf</color>
<color name="colorBlack">#000000</color>

</style>
```

Comment: Please post also the error/warning you are receiving and more information about when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Colors are **"Resources"**
Put your colors in between this tag `<Resources> //Colors here  </Resources>`